# Referencing parent theme image from child theme

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I've had some trouble finding the solution via Google.

I've set up a parent theme and a child theme. Inside the parent theme I have a directory named img which contains a number of images I want to use in the child theme too.

The problem is, I can't seem to find the best way to reference an image from the parent theme whilst inside the child theme. Surely there is a particular way to reference the path dynamically?

Whilst in the child theme, using `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/` seems to look for the `img` folder inside the child theme, but I am looking to reference the img folder inside the parent folder.

Any help on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` to reference your parent theme folders.

From the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri):

*In the event a child theme is being used, the parent theme directory URI will be returned...*